# JavaScript created Inputs, now i need to get the value of those

Tags: javascript

I have some script where i have created a Table in Javascript,
in one of the columns it has an Input. now, upon submit i would
like to get the data entered in the input so it can be saved.
here is my code. it will be ugly, sorry!

here is how i have created my table.
schedArray created in another function.

```
function schedTable() {
    var tableCode = '<table id="longCallData" width="99.5%"> <tr> <th>' + schedArray[1][0] + '</th> <th>' + schedArray[1][1] + '</th> <th>' + schedArray[1][2] + '</th><th>' + schedArray[1][3] + '</th> <th>' + schedArray[1][4] + '</th> <th>' + schedArray[1][5] + '</th><th>' + schedArray[1][6] + '</th> <th>' + schedArray[1][7] + '</th> <th>' + schedArray[1][8] + '</th><th>' + schedArray[1][9] + '</th> <th>' + schedArray[1][10] + '</th></tr>';
    var oddeven = new Boolean();

    for (i = 2; i < schedArray.length; i++) {
        oddeven = !oddeven;
        tableCode += 'enter code here<tr class="row' + oddeven + '">';
        tableCode += '<th>' + schedArray[i][0] + '</th> <th>**<input type="text" name="sched">**</th> <th>' + schedArray[i][2] + '</th><th>' + schedArray[i][3] + '</th> <th>' + schedArray[i][4] + '</th> <th>' + schedArray[i][5] + '</th><th>' + schedArray[i][6] + '</th> <th>' + schedArray[i][7] + '</th> <th>' + schedArray[i][8] + '</th><th>' + schedArray[i][9] + '</th> <th>' + schedArray[i][10] + '</th></tr>';
    }

    tableCode += '</table>';
    var tabSpan = document.getElementById('shiftTable');    //Get display location
    tabSpan.innerHTML = tableCode;  //Place data in display element

    var count = schedArray.length - 2;
    var counted = schedArray.length - 2;
    var ctnSpan = document.getElementById('countOne');  //Get display location
    ctnSpan.innerHTML = count;  //Place data in display element
    var cntSpan = document.getElementById('countTwo');  //Get display location
    cntSpan.innerHTML = counted;    //Place data in display element
}
```

after the user adds their info, they hit the submit button which onclick="submit()".
notes is the text are in the html, choice is the var for the column.
i have attempted a few things here and there including making a new array
and manipulating that, but i am always getting a Null. one time i was able
to get the top of the original array but none of the other data in that array.

```
function submit() {
    var message = confirm("This Will Submit Your Bid And Close Out The Form, Are You Sure You Are Ready To Submit?", "");
    if (message != null && message != "") {
        var extras = document.getElementById('notes').value;
        var choice = " ";

        var s = Fo.OpenTextFile('file.csv', 8, true, 0);

        s.WriteLine(user.Name + ',' + user.ID + ',,' + choice + ',' + extras);
        s.Close();
        alert("Thank You!");
    }
}
```

If I use a document.getElementBy***('sched').value with or with out value,
*** has been name, class,tag and name using other code with no success.

below is the whole code may be better useful:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>


    <HTA:APPLICATION ID="Shift_Bid" 
    APPLICATIONNAME="ShiftBid" 
    BORDER="thin"
    CAPTION="yes"
    SHOWINTASKBAR="yes"
    SINGLEINSTANCE="Yes"
    SYSMENU="yes"
    selection="no"
    minimize="yes"
    >

<title>Shift Bid</title>

    <style type="text/css">
    body {overflow:hidden;}

    #titleBid {position:absolute; top:10px; left:160px;}
    #nameSpace {position:absolute; top:50px; left:200px;}
    #oracleSpace {position:absolute; top:50px; left:400px;}
    #agentName {border:1px solid black;}
    #agentOracle {border:1px solid black;}
    #info {position:absolute; top:70px; left:120px; font-size:20px; font-weight:bolder;}
    #contentSpace {position:absolute; top:100px; left:5px; width:1250px; height:480px; border:1px solid black; overflow:hidden;}
    #countBid {position:absolute; top:580px; left:120px; font-size:20px; font-weight:bolder;}
    #notAtion {position:absolute; top:610px; left:5px; width:1250px; height:120px; border:1px solid black; overflow:hidden;}
    #comment {position:absolute; top:5px; left:10px; font-size:15pt;}
    #notes {position:absolute; top:30px; left:5px; width:1000px; height:80px; border:1px solid black; overflow:hidden;}
    #action {position:absolute; top:2px; left:1016px; width:228px; height:114px; padding-left:2px; border:1px solid black; font-size:12pt; font-weight:bolder;}
    #submit {position:absolute; top:79px; left:23px; width:180px; height:30px; background-color:green; font-size:15pt; font-weight:bolder;}
    table input {width:15px;}
    table {border-collapse:collapse; font-size:10pt; margin-left:2px;}
    table th {border-top:1px solid black; font-weight:bolder;}
    .rowfalse{background-color: #E6E6E6;}
    .rowtrue{background-color: #FFFFFF;}
    table th:hover {font-size:12pt;}

    </style>


<script>


window.resizeTo(1310,800);
var Fo = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var network = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Network');
var objSysInfo = new ActiveXObject("ADSystemInfo")
var objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" + objSysInfo.UserName)
var user = {'Name': objUser.displayName, 'ID': objUser.sAMAccountName}
var dir = "//directory/of/file";


getForm();



function getAgent(){
    var name = user.Name;
    var oracle = user.ID;

var nameSpan = document.getElementById('agentName'); 
nameSpan.innerHTML = '  ' + name + '  '; 

var oracleSpan = document.getElementById('agentOracle'); 
oracleSpan.innerHTML = '  ' + oracle + '  ';

    nameSpan.style.color = "#006600"; 
    oracleSpan.style.color = "#006600"; 
}





function getForm() {
var dataPath = dir + '/Agent_Form.csv'; 
if(Fo.FileExists(dataPath)){ 
    var dataFile = Fo.OpenTextFile(dataPath,1); 
    schedArray = new Array(); 
    while(!dataFile.AtEndOfStream){ 
        var line = dataFile.Line - 1; 
        schedArray[line] = dataFile.readLine(); 
    }
    dataFile.close();
    for(i=0;i<schedArray.length;i++){
        schedArray[i] = schedArray[i].split(",");
    }
}
}



function getStuff(){
getAgent();
getTitle();
schedTable();
}



function startUp(){
getForm();
getStuff();
}   


function getTitle(){
var title = schedArray[0][1];

var titleData = title;


var titleSpan = document.getElementById('titleBid'); 
titleSpan.innerHTML = '<h1>' + titleData + '</h1>';

}   

function schedTable(){
var tableCode = '<table id="longCallData" width="99.5%"> <tr> <th>' + schedArray[1][0] + '</th> <th>' + schedArray[1][1] + '</th> <th>' + schedArray[1][2] + '</th><th>' + schedArray[1][3] + '</th> <th>' + schedArray[1][4] + '</th> <th>' + schedArray[1][5] + '</th><th>' + schedArray[1][6] + '</th> <th>' + schedArray[1][7] + '</th> <th>' + schedArray[1][8] + '</th><th>' + schedArray[1][9] + '</th> <th>' + schedArray[1][10] + '</th></tr>';
var oddeven = new Boolean();
for(i=2;i<schedArray.length;i++){
oddeven = !oddeven;
tableCode += '<tr class="row'+ oddeven +'">';
tableCode += '<th>' + schedArray[i][0] + '</th> <th><input type="text" name="sched"></th> <th>' + schedArray[i][2] + '</th><th>' + schedArray[i][3] + '</th> <th>' + schedArray[i][4] + '</th> <th>' + schedArray[i][5] + '</th><th>' + schedArray[i][6] + '</th> <th>' + schedArray[i][7] + '</th> <th>' + schedArray[i][8] + '</th><th>' + schedArray[i][9] + '</th> <th>' + schedArray[i][10] + '</th></tr>';

}

tableCode += '</table>';
var tabSpan = document.getElementById('shiftTable'); 
tabSpan.innerHTML = tableCode; 

var count = schedArray.length - 2;
var counted = schedArray.length - 2;
var ctnSpan = document.getElementById('countOne');
ctnSpan.innerHTML = count; 
var cntSpan = document.getElementById('countTwo'); 
cntSpan.innerHTML = counted; 

}





 function submit(){
var message = confirm("This Will Submit Your Bid And Close Out The Form, Are You Sure You Are Ready To Submit?", "");
if( message!=null && message!=""){
        var extras = document.getElementById('notes').value;

        var tabSpan = document.getElementById('shiftTable');
        tabSpan.getElementsByName("sched")[0].value;
var s = Fo.OpenTextFile('file.csv', 8, true, 0);

s.WriteLine(user.Name+','+user.ID+',,'+tabSpan+','+extras);
s.Close();
alert("Thank You!");
}
}   


</script>

</head>

<body onload="startUp()">

<div id="main" >

<div id="agentSpace">

<span id="titleBid"></span>
<div id="nameSpace">
Name :
<span id="agentName"> </span>
</div>
<div id="oracleSpace">
Oracle :
<span id="agentOracle"> </span>
</div>
<div id="info">Please make sure to enter your name and oracle in the fields below.</div>
</div>
<div id="contentSpace">
<span id="shiftTable"></span>
</div>
<div id="countBid">Please list choices from 1-<span id="countOne"></span>, all fields need to be numbered. Top choice is 1, bottom choice is <span id="countTwo"></span>.</div>
<div id="notAtion"><div id="comment">Comments: (ie. Public transportation needs to include what the earliest start and end times)</div><input id="notes" value=""><div id="action">Please Review Your Selections and Make Note if you have Concerns. Then Submit Your Bid. Thank You!<button id="submit"onclick="submit()">Submit</button></div></div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: When you select by `name`, you get a collection in return. So if there's only one `input` with that name, you'd need to access index `[0]` of the collection. I don't know where your `onsubmit()` is located, but if there's one per row, you could change it a bit, and just traverse over to the `input` for that row.

Comment: And your question would be easier to understand if you'd apply clean indentation to your code, and make some of your sentences a little clearer.

Comment: I have updated the entry with the whole code.... onsubmit() is in the html on a button.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it could come from the fact that you call **getElementByName** instead of **getElementsByName**.

**getElementsByName** returns an array, so you should try like this :

```
document.getElementsByName("sched")[0].value
```

But you will have to be sure that have only one object that is named *sched*, or know its index.

Maybe you should also try with the DOM :
    var tabSpan = document.getElementById('shiftTable');

```
// Create table
table = document.createElement("table");

// Create table header lines
tableHeaderLine = document.createElement("tr");
for (j = 0; i <= 10; j++)
{
    cell = document.createElement("th");
    cell.innerHTML = schedArray[1][j];
    tableHeaderLine.appendChild(cell);
}

// Create table lines
for (i = 2; i < schedArray.length; i++)
{
    line = document.createElement("tr");
    table.appendChild(line);

    for (j = 0; i <= 10; j++)
    {
        cell = document.createElement("th");

        if (j == 1)
        {
            schedInput = document.createElement("input");
            schedInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
            schedInput.name = "sched";
            cell.appendChild(schedInput);
        }
        else
        {
            cell.innerHTML = schedArray[i][j];
        }
    }  
}

// Append table to tabSpan
tabSpan.appendChild(table);
```

Using DOM will permit you to prevent errors coming from HTML Parser when calling *innerHTML* method.
In this code *innerHTML* is used separately each time, and you create the input in pure DOM, so you're sure error doesn't come from the parser.

Comment: i have tried this and others, with that code its giving me an error "object doesn' support property or method 'getElementByName'" which i have see it give that error a few times but not others, with any getElement

Comment: Are you sure you tried getElementsByName ? You have to put a S to Element, to put it in the plural.

Comment: i have added my whole code.... maybe it will help... i have added your suggestion, although i have removed it from the full code. i have tried even making another function called with in the submit function that does the getting and array building.... still nothing

Comment: var choice =" ";
   var taskArray = new Array();
    $("input[name=sched]").each(function() {
   taskArray.push($(this).val());
   });
  for(i=0;i<taskArray.length;i++){
  choice+=taskArray[i][0];
  }

Comment: var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('input');  
  var arr = new Array();
  var i = 0;
  var iarr = 0;
  var att;
   for(; i < elem.length; i++) {
    att = elem[i].getAttribute("name");
    if(att == name) {
     arr[iarr] = elem[i];
     iarr++;
    }
return arr;
    }

Comment: just a few things i have tried, the last one stops the code, the first errors with $ in unknown

Comment: http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html could be helpful for you, and people trying to read your code.

Comment: I have attempted a few more things and am either getting "null" or errors that getElementBy*** is not working. Any further help?

Comment: I added a DOM way, you should try like this.

Comment: I have got it to not error out, but when it writes to the file all of the entries are undefined toying with something simple....          var choice = " ";
   
   var chooseArray = document.getElementsByName('sched'); 
   for (i=0;i<chooseArray.length;i++){
    choice +=chooseArray[i][2]+',';
   }

Comment: You never use the value. choice += chooseArray[i].value should work.